# 2D version of LeetCode house robber problem

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

The [house robber problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/) of leetcode can be described as followed :

> A robber enters a colony of houses numbered from 1 to n.  Every house has a number printed on the top of it.  That number is the amount of money inside that house. However, there is one constraint. If the robber robs the i-th house, he can't rob house no i-1 and house no i+1. How can the robber maximise his robbery?

Apparently, this is a classical problem in dynamic programming, which can be solved in linear complexity: See [here](https://csjobinterview.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/the-robbers-problem-4/) and [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent/).

My question : what about the 2D version ? if the houses are not on a line, but on a 2D grid ? Like for the 1D version, if you rob one house, you cannot rob the adjacent ones (see the following pattern) :

x x x
x o x
x x x

Can DP be used to solve that ? Is it even linearly solvable ?

Comment: This problem is a restriction of the problem from [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42978/is-this-problem-np-hard/42981#42981) where I provided a pretty sketchy proof sketch of NP-hardness.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden : thank you for the link. So here you advise to represent the grid as a graph and the problem as a minimum vertex cover ? When you say it's NP-hard, do you mean in the strong sense ?

Comment: @TomvanderZanden what if the houses are arranged in a circular fashion  how does the solution change?

Answer (score -1):

[I found a question which is similar to the 2D version of house robber](https://binarysearch.com/problems/Collecting-Disappearing-Coins)

If you observe carefully we can calculate the answer for each row independently and that leads us to our solution.

Here is my solution for it

```
class Solution {
    public int solve(int[][] matrix) {
        int N = matrix.length;
        if(N == 0)
        return 0;
        int[] arr = new int[N];
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        arr[i] = DP(matrix[i]);
        int ans = DP(arr);
        return ans;        
    }

    public int DP(int[] arr) {
        int[] dp = new int[arr.length + 1];
        dp[0] = 0;
        dp[1] = arr[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            dp[i + 1] = Math.max(dp[i],dp[i - 1] + arr[i]);
        }
        return dp[arr.length];
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to explain in plain English, what it does? Links tend to rot, could you write summary or quote relevant parts?